# Azure DevOps API Combine OData Queries?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the following 3 queries in order to get a list of Task/User Story/Feature relationship in a given Sprint (Iteration)

I'm no Odata expert, but it would seem in some way I could combine the 3 queries into 1 to retrieve Task, Parent (User Story) Parent (Feature) and associated Assigned Usernames.

Is this possible or could this be done another way?

**Get Task and parent User Stories**

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{org}/{projectName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=AssignedToUserSK,WorkItemId,Title,State,WorkItemType,ParentWorkItemId,RemainingWork,CompletedWork,OriginalEstimate&$expand=Parent($select=WorkItemId,Title,State,WorkItemType,ParentWorkItemId,StoryPoints,StackRank)&$filter=Iteration/IterationPath eq '{sprint}' and WorkItemType eq 'Task'";
```

**Get parent Feature of User Stories (from above)**

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{org}/{projectName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=WorkItemId, Title, State, &$filter=WorkItemId in ({parentStoryFeatureIdsStr})
```

**Get Work Item and Assigned User Name**

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{org}/{projectName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=WorkItemId,&$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName)&$filter=Iteration/IterationPath eq '{sprint}' and WorkItemType eq 'Task'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try using `$expand` on `Descendants` to query `Feature` and its decendants work items(`User Story` and `Task`). See below example:

`https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{org}/{projectName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$filter=WorkItemType eq 'Feature'&$expand=Descendants($filter=Iteration/IterationPath eq '{sprint}'; $select=AssignedToUserSK,WorkItemId,Title,State,WorkItemType,ParentWorkItemId,RemainingWork,CompletedWork,OriginalEstimate;$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName)）`

Using `$expand` on `Descendants` will return all the children User Stories and grandchildren Tasks of the Feature work items.

If you have to use `$expand` on `Parent` to query from Tasks to Parent User Stories and then to Parent Feature. I am afraid it is impossible to combine the 3 queries into 1. For the maximum depth allowed for `$expand` on `Parent` is 1 .

However, You can combine the 3 queries into 2 like below(combine the 3rd query into the 1st query):

`https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{org}/{projectName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=AssignedToUserSK,WorkItemId,Title,State,WorkItemType,ParentWorkItemId,RemainingWork,CompletedWork,OriginalEstimate&$expand=Parent($select=WorkItemId,Title,State,WorkItemType,ParentWorkItemId,StoryPoints,StackRank),AssignedTo($select=UserName)&$filter=Iteration/IterationPath eq '{sprint}' and WorkItemType eq 'Task'"`

Comment: This helped me greatly! I need to go bottom up (Task => Story => Feature) because our Tasks/Stories get Slotted in a a Sprint, while the Feature may not (backlog). Finally, is it possible to "join in" to the one OData query the Assigned Users Capacity? Or do I have to do a completely separate query for that?

Comment: Also - why is it only possible to $expand Parent 1, is that an ODATA limitation or a MSFT enforced limitation? Would be great for me if I could expand 2.

Comment: @aherrick I am afraid it is a msft enforced limitation. You can [submit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) regarding this issue.

Comment: @aherrick Could you explain more about joining in to the one OData query the `Assigned Users Capacity`? Did you mean querying the `Assigned User` in the odata query?

Comment: thanks! I'll look into making that suggestion. Regarding the join, I'm really just looking to have 1 query to get the WorkItemTask, AssignedUser, and AssignedUserCapacity. Right now, I have to have a separate query just to get all users capacity and then link them up in memory.

Comment: @aherrick Could you share your current query to get  all users capacity?

Comment: https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{projectName}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/{iterationId}/capacities?api-version=6.0

Comment: @aherrick I afraid you will have to query the users capacity separately. Retrieve user capacity  with ODATA is not supported yet. See [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/retrieve-user-capacity-for-an-iteration-with-odata/155450?viewtype=solutions)

Comment: from 2017 crying :D appreciate all your help